# Call Method from other Class in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, instantiation

I have 2 view controller classes. I want to call a method of ViewController2 from ViewController, but the console gives me this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>       (lldb)

Here is my method in the ViewController class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBAction func testButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        ViewController2().setText("It's a Test!")
    }
}
```

And here is some code from ViewController2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var directionsTextField: UITextView!


    func setText(var fieldText:String){
            directionsTextField.text = directionsTextField.text + "\n \n" + fieldText
    }
}
```

I'd be glad for every help! :-)

Thank you in advance :)

### EDIT:

I also get this:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

on the setText method...
Seems like `directionsTextField` isn't yet there maybe(??)

Comment: Why not use the delegation pattern? Is exactly for what you want to achieve here is the `UIViewControllers` are related (segue, etc)

Comment: How do I do that? I don't know how to use a delegation pattern or maybe I just don't exactly know what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close to figuring it out yourself. The crash is because your `directionsTextField` does not yet exist. Being an IBOutlet it won't come into existence before `viewDidLoad` is called. How do you fix this?

You change your API for your `SecondViewController`and give it a `directionsText` property. Winding up with something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var directionsTextField: UITextView!
var directionsText = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    directionsTextField.text = directionsTextField.text + "\n\n\(directionsText)"
}
```

In your `FirstViewController` you change your IBAction to match the new API of the `SecondViewController`:

```
@IBAction func testButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let secondController = SecondViewController() // Felt a bit odd creating an instance without having a way of referencing it afterwards.
    secondController.directionsText = "It's a test"
    // Do what you want. (Perhaps pushing your secondController)
}
```

Comment: you mean
directionsTextField.text = directionsTextField.text + "\n\n\(directionsText)", right?

Comment: Yup, that's one of them typo-thingies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I finally got it working. The way you wrote was not applicable 1:1 inside my "real" method I'm working in, so I had to add some "prepareForSegue" thing, but I think I will make a second try to implement it the way you did. Somehow, directionsText was empty / blank... Maybe it's set to "" when the class loads?

Comment: Yes, the default-value is "". If you set a value in prepareForSegue in the FirstViewController and implement viewDidLoad like above in the SecondViewController it should work fine.

Comment: That's exactly the way I did it :-) Thanks again I would like to give you +1 but I can't (reputation) :/

Comment: No worries. We've all been there. :-)

Comment: I'll +1 it. Good answer

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen I 1-uppped you now :D Almost 1,5 years later but still :)

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you try instance the Second ViewController. Because you need implement the `init` method.

For example:

```
public class FirstViewController : UIViewController {

   public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let secondviewController = SecondViewController().setText("YOURTEXT")

}

}
```

The Second ViewController:

```
public class SecondtViewController: UIViewController {

public required init(coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder : aDecoder)
}

public init(nibName nibNameOrNil : String){
    super.init(nibName : nibNameOrNil, bundle: SBTVPayViewController.frameworkBundle())
}

public convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName: "MyNibName")
}

public func setText(texto : String) {

    directionsTextField.text = directionsTextField.text + "\n \n" + fieldText


}

}
```

When you try to instantiate a ViewController the first method to execute it's `init`

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast and good answer, but I still get the error somehow..
    fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Try to define de value of the func not optional. `func setText(var fieldText:String!)`